# What causes these two different ways of joining in data.table to use twice as much memory?

Tags: r, data.table

I have been working with `data.table` joins of the format `x[y, on = .(join), col := i.col]`.

When there are many columns to join from table `y`, it is convenient to use `mget` to shorten the amount of code needed to manually type out all the columns.

However, I've noticed that the `mget` uses twice as much memory and time as manually typing out the columns in `y`.

This suggests that a copy is taking place somewhere but I'm not sure where and why this is happening.

I'd like to know how using `mget` is causing the additional resource consumption!

Below is code to replicate the two joining approaches.

```
library(data.table)
library(profvis)

set.seed(42)

# Data to join
data1 <- function() {
  dt_1 <- as.data.table(matrix(rnorm(1e7 * 5), ncol = 5))
  dt_1[, join := sample.int(1e5, 1e7, replace = TRUE)]
  
  return(dt_1)
}

data2 <- function() {
  dt_2 <- as.data.table(matrix(rnorm(1e5 * 5), ncol = 5))
  dt_2[, join := sample.int(1e5, 1e5)]
  setnames(dt_2, new = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "join"))
  
  return(dt_2)
}

# Bench 2
dt_1 <- data1()
dt_2 <- data2()

profvis({
  dt_1[dt_2, on = .(join), (names(dt_2)) := mget(paste0("i.", names(dt_2)))]
})

# Bench 3
dt_1 <- data1()
dt_2 <- data2()

profvis({
  dt_1[dt_2, on = .(join), 
       `:=`(X1 = i.X1,
            X2 = i.X2,
            X3 = i.X3,
            X4 = i.X4,
            X5 = i.X5)]
})
```

Comment: It needs to materialize more data internally than not using mget. In devel version of DT there is new 'env' argument that give what mget (and much more) gives without any overhead. Read new vignette about programming with DT for examples how to replace mget with env.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me there @jangorecki, will have a read!